# How to pass parameters to the sub page through onGenerateRoute in flutter program

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following a tutorial on a website to study flutter/dart. the tutorial techs me how to pass parameters (a Map) in named route through `onGenerateRoute`. now, I have created 2 `webpage`, say, main page and sub page, on my main page I created a button, if I clicked the button, it would route me to sub page with parameters. however, my program always stuck at error
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

It's frustrated after many attempts. I appreciate that if somebody can show root cause in detailed.
I'm using flutter 3.16.5, and dart is 3.2.3

I checked the variables

```
by print(settings); 
print(settings.arguments);           
print(settings.name);
it returns 
I/flutter ( 4675): RouteSettings("/subpage", {title: pass parameter in named route})
I/flutter ( 4675): {title: pass parameter in named route}
I/flutter ( 4675): /subpage
```

I don't understand why the flutter still reported type error

below program for your reference:

```
//-----------------------------this is main page
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firstapp/testsubpage.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map routes={
    '/': (context) => const ShowPage(),
    '/subpage':(context,{arguments}) => SubPage(args: arguments,),
  };

  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            useMaterial3:true,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
            appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.blue)
        ),
//      home: const ShowPage()
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute:(RouteSettings settings){
          String? name=settings.name;
          Function pageContentBuilder = routes[name];
          if(pageContentBuilder != null){
            if(settings.arguments !=null){
              final Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pageContentBuilder(settings.arguments));

              print(settings);
              print(settings.arguments);
              print(settings.name);

//              return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
//                return pageContentBuilder('/subpage', settings.arguments);});
              return route;
            }else{
              final Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>pageContentBuilder(context));
              return route;
            }
          }
          return null;
        }
    );
  }
}

class ShowPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ShowPage> createState() => _ShowPageState();
}

class _ShowPageState extends State<ShowPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter Named Route'),),
      body: Center(
          child: OutlinedButton(onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/subpage', arguments: {'title':'pass parameter in named route'});
          }, child: const Text('Click Me'),)
      )
      ,
    );
  }
}


//-----this is sub page
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SubPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map args;
  const SubPage({super.key, required this.args});
  @override
  State<SubPage> createState() => _SubPageState();
}

class _SubPageState extends State<SubPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:  Text(widget.args['title']),),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('This is sub page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the error was in here:
*final Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pageContentBuilder(settings.arguments));*

after changed it to
final Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pageContentBuilder(context, arguments:settings.arguments));

the program is running normally.

I supposed that I misunderstand this part:

```
final Map routes={
'/': (context) => const ShowPage(),
'/subpage':(context,{arguments}) => SubPage(args: arguments,),};
...
Function pageContentBuilder = routes[name];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `onGenerateRoute` parameter, the example / my code is

```dart
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings rs) { 
  Map<String, dynamic> args = {};
  if (rs.arguments != null) { 
    args = rs.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }
  return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
    settings: rs,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      switch (rs.name) { 
        case DiapositiveVideoFullplayView.routeName: 
          return DiapositiveVideoFullplayView(
                    settings: settings, 
                    videoId: args["videoId"], 
                    episodeId: args["episodeId"],
                );

        case SettingsView.routeName: return SettingsView(settings: settings);
        case GeneralWebAccess.routeName: return GeneralWebAccess(url: args["url"]);

        default: return Container();
      }
    },
  );
},
```

When you push a new page, the `arguments` parameter will pass to that page, the follow is my code:

```
var args = {"videoId": widget.videoId, "episodeId": widget.episodeId}; 
Navigator.pushNamed(
    context, 
    DiapositiveVideoFullplayView.routeName, 
    arguments: args,
);
```